# how to send a POST request to download a file using rn-fetch-blob?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I'm using [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob) library to download and save a file into the device, and I've been successful to do it with GET request like: `.fetch('GET', "http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert?access_key=MY_ACCESS_KEY&document_url=URL_PATH")`, but the API that I use just accepts post request, so I tried this but didn't work:

```
const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
let DownloadDir = fs.dirs.DownloadDir;
let options = {
  fileCache: true,
  addAndroidDownloads : {
    useDownloadManager : true,
    path: DownloadDir + "/file.pdf"
  }
};
const data = JSON.stringify({
  access_key: "MY_ACCESS_KEY",
  document_url: "https://pdflayer.com/downloads/invoice.html"
});
config(options)
  .fetch('POST', 'http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert', {body: data})
    .then((res) => {
       console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
    })
```

If I'm not sending my request correctly, so how should I do it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to the rn-fetch-blob's document :

> headers:object (Optional) Headers of HTTP request, the value of
>   headers should be stringified, if you're uploading binary files,
>   content-type should be application/octet-stream or
>   multipart/form-data(see examples above).
>
> body:string | Array (Optional) Body of the HTTP request, body
>   can either be a BASE64 string, or an array contains object elements,
>   each element have 2 required property name, data, and optional
>   property filename, once filename is set, content in data property will
>   be considered as a path to a file or a BASE64 string which will be
>   converted into byte array later.

I think you should define content-type for your request and change your code like these examples :

```
// Post binary data using base64 encoding
RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://myupload.com/upload', { 
        'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream' 
    }, RNFetchBlob.base64.encode(mydata))

// Post binary data from existing file
RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://myupload.com/upload', { 
        'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream' 
    }, RNFetchBlob.wrap(path_to_the_file))

// Post form data 
RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'http://myupload.com/upload', { 
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data' 
    }, [
        { name : 'user_name', data : 'Bill' },
        // binary field data from a file path, use `wrap` method to wrap the path
        { name : 'avatar', filename : 'avatar.jpg', data : RNFetchBlob.wrap(path_to_the_file) },
        // binary field data encoded in BASE64
        { name : 'pet-avatar', filename : 'pet-avatar.jpg', data : RNFetchBlob.base64.encode(image_data) },
    ])
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: @BlueTurtle change your content-type to "multipart/form-data"

Comment: I did, but nothing changed!, I've tested this API in postman and I could send a post request with exactly the same data and getting a file, I'm sure there is something wrong with my request

Comment: do you know any alternative library that can do what I need?

Comment: @BlueTurtle Maybe your problem is related to something else, however, you could use XMLHttpRequest, Frisbee or axios library instead.